# Possibility of analyzing the hypothesis using Friedman's test 

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, tables

Lets assume I have collected some data about sold ice creams on the local market on the daily basis. Days( just a number of observations, might be classified otherwise, it's not variable ) present the day collection of data took place, var1 represents sold ice creams between 09:00-10:00, var2 between 12:00-13:00, and var3 between 16:00-17:00. My Q. is,

**Is it possible to conduct Friedman's test on this data with hypothesis** 
   H0: Time of the day isn't the cause factor for the size of the traffic. 
   H1: At least one time of the day causes on the size of the traffic.

Friedman's test is as we know used for 3+ dependent variables, however none of those variables depend on each other. So is it possible to conduct such a test on this type of data, or should I use more appropriate K-W, or perhaps Cochran Q test.

> days  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
>
> var1  42  16  98  67  53  23  45  72  6   5
>
> var2  23  34  12  53  12  42  51  62  73  74
>
> var3  32  12  53  25  64  43  23  73  23  34

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To help us formulate good replies, please tell us the objective of your data collection activities.  Data, by themselves, do not suggest hypotheses (or statistical tests): *you* come up with the hypotheses and then statistical theory can help us suggest appropriate procedures.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of doing as many as possible tests ( to practice myself in R ), however I am not sure can I apply all those tests to my data. So, objective is to conclude what tests are possible to conduct on this data, and that's all. The thing is I don't know what to use when, and is it possible to conduct more tests on one data?

Comment: Please consult our FAQ: I believe it will suggest a question like this is too broad for this site: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  Please modify this question to narrow its scope.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I should reformulate my Q.

Comment: You might have taken a little effort to find out yourself that Cochran Q = Friedman when variables are dichotomous, and that Kendall W is just a standardized form of Friedman statistic.

Comment: Of course,@ttnphns. I have done some research in the mean time, and found out, that Cochran Q and Friedmans are not good for this type of data, mainly because the first is used only for dichotomous data, and the second is used with dependent data, and both scenarios aren't reliable for my data. Instead, I should use K-W test. Do you have anything to add on this move of myself?